# MS Access Insert Into Select Does not work with vba

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to run an insert into select query like this:

```
Dim rs as new ADODB.recordset
rs.Open "INSERT INTO tempTable(PartNumber, Age, Height, Notes, UpdateType)" & _
        " SELECT PartNumber, Age, Height, Notes, UpdateType FROM TABLE2", CurrentProject.Connection, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic
```

which gives me an error:

> Syntax Error in INSERT INTO statment

What is really weird is that when I debug.print the above statement and run the query from the query wizard in Access database it runs just fine.

My understanding of `currentproject.connection` has been that I can happily use the Jet-SQL or  MS Access query syntax so if the query runs in the query window in Access it should run in VBA as well. Seems like that is not the case.

Here are a few other things I have tried to make the code run:

```
CurrentProject.Connection.Execute "INSERT INTO tempTable(PartNumber, Age, Height, Notes, UpdateType)" & _
        " SELECT PartNumber, Age, Height, Notes, UpdateType FROM TABLE2"
```

This gives the same error as above.

I also tried to add a new line `vbclrf`:

```
rs.Open "INSERT INTO tempTable(PartNumber, Age, Height, Notes, UpdateType)" & _
        & vbclrf & " SELECT PartNumber, Age, Height, Notes, UpdateType FROM TABLE2", CurrentProject.Connection, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic
```

but it gave me the same error

Comment: Why are you duplicating records into tempTable and not just using a query?

Comment: Tested and brackets are not needed. Something else causes Execute to fail. Although what I see should work.

Comment: I am duplicating records into a temp table because I want to display it in a form in datasheet view. I know I can use a query for that as well but I want to add a checkbox next to each record. I want to checkbox value to be whatever the use set even when the user closes the form and comes back. So I have to use a temp table for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only SELECT statements are used to set a recordset object. A recordset is not needed.

INSERT is an action SQL so for VBA constructed statement, use DoCmd.RunSQL or CurrentDb.Execute or CurrentProject.Connection.Execute.

My preference is: `CurrentDb.Execute "your SQL statement here"`