# Copy records from one Table into another by VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a DB that collects input via a Form"Abgabe_Unterlagen" into a Table "Abgabe_Unterlagen."

Tables and Form:

[image]

After all actions are taken and records are completed the user enters a date in the field "Datum_Weiterg"

Once a day a query is run to filter the records from the table where " Datum_Weiterg" Is NOT NULL and do an append into a new table "Ordner_Liste"

After the records are in the new table, they will be deleted from the "Abgabe_Unterlagen." table.

Query ...

[image]

This is awkward an a little complicated.
It would be more elegant and take less effort if this could be done by VBA code.

Would anyone be able to assist ?

Comment: You can use `docmd.runsql` .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MS Access Insert Into Select Does not work with vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65403019/ms-access-insert-into-select-does-not-work-with-vba)

Comment: Review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28372889/how-to-use-a-insert-into-select-query-in-access-vba

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution of Gustav will work.

The same can be achieved using one append query (to transfer the recently added records to the table Ordner_Liste) and one update query (to set the transfered dates Datum_Kopiert in table Abgabe_Unterlagen). If the final target is to delete the transfered records you could as well use a delete query instead of the update query right away (new field Datum_Kopiert is not strictly required then).

If both tables have the same fields this will work:

INSERT INTO Ordner_Liste.* SELECT * FROM Abgabe_Unterlagen WHERE Datum_Weiterg Is Not Null

and then

DELETE * FROM Abgabe_Unterlagen WHERE Datum_Weiterg Is Not Null

If large numbers of records are involved in the operation (hundreds or thousands) using action queries will be definitely faster than looping over recordsets.

Action queries can be executed in VBA using

```
CurrentDb.Execute "NameOfYourActionQuery"
```

or

```
DoCmd.SetWarnings false 
DoCmd.OpenQuery "NameOfYourActionQuery" 
DoCmd.SetWarnings true
```

Comment: Thank you Gert, I'll try with the record set, but really like your suggestion of calling a Query...
I think it won't be that many records

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a date field,`Datum_Kopiert`, to table Abgabe_Unterlagen
2. Add a filter to the form or it recordsource: `Datum_Kopiert Is Null`
3. Add a button to copy the latest records which runs code like this:

```vb
Private Sub CopyButton_Click()

    Dim Source      As DAO.Recordset
    Dim Target      As DAO.Recordset
    
    Set Source = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select * From Abgabe_Unterlagen Where Datum_Weiterg Is Not Null And Datum_Kopiert Is Null")
    Set Target = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select * From Ordner_Liste")
    
    If Source.RecordCount > 0 Then
        Source.MoveFirst
        While Not Source.EOF
            ' Copy record.
            Target.AddNew
                ' Copy fields.
                Target!Field1.Value = Source!Field1.Value
                Target!Field1.Value = Source!Field1.Value
                ' etc.
                Target!FieldN.Value = Source!FieldN.Value
            Target.Update
            ' Mark record as copied.
            Source.Edit
                Source!Datum_Kopiert.Value = Now
            Source.Update
            Source.MoveNext
        Wend
    End If
    Target.Close
    Source.Close

End Sub
```

Note, that this will not delete the source records, only mark them as copied.

Comment: Thank you very much for the code snippet...looks like a perfect match for the task.

Comment: I'll test it,  2 questions before I start...
would it be sufficient to set the Standardwert "Default Value" for the field "Datum_Kopiert" in the Table to "Null"  or would there be a better fit ?

To delete the copied records , I could run a query to "Abgabe_Unterlagen " to delete all records where 

````
"Datum_Kopiert  IS NOT NULL"  ?
````

Comment: Yes and yes. Default values for target fields will work as well.